# WINE only Linux distribution?

Tags: virtual-machines, wine

Are there any Linux distributions that are intended exclusivity for running windows programs under WINE?

My particular use case is that I have a windows program that I'd like to install in a VM (I'd rather not install it on any of my system) but I don't want to go through the hassle of setting up windows in a VM (last time I tried, it didn't work for some reason and I don't feel like debugging it).

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Wine forums](http://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=14191&sid=ba658c503691749297109b6958096601), there is no one favored Linux distribution. For optimal stability and performance, you are definitely well-advised to invest in the commercial version of wine ([CrossOver](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/)). They optimize builds for a short list of specific popular Windows applications.

With that said, I have always had the best luck with a combination of Ubuntu and Wine. The abundance of users results in lots of excellent bug reports from which the Wine team benefits greatly. If it's not a niche program, it's also almost guaranteed that someone else has tried your software with Wine on Ubuntu.